# Anchor tags in Angular - how do they work?

Tags: angular, hyperlink

I'm new to Angular and I noticed this strange behavior: anchor tags don't work when I click on the text inside.

I have this:

```js
<a href="{{ downloadAddress }}"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
```

downloadAddress is the address for my back end function, it works fine. If I click on the icon the request is sent and the file downloaded. However if I click on the "Download" text nothing happens - no request, no error.

If I separate the icon and text into two hyperlinks with the same href the result is the same - the icon download works, the text doesn't. I also tried with [href].

I'm using Angle Template if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdpzpy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. If you want help, you'll need to provide a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the target in the tag and the download should work fine.

```
<a href="{{ downloadAddress }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> 
  Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but that made no difference. However, strangely enough, what worked was to surround my text in a span:
<a href="{{ downloadAddress }}"><i class="fa fa-download"></i><span> Download</span></a>